# Getting same numbers within two event methods on windows form

Tags: winforms, random, event-handling

I have created a from which takes the user input and compares it to 100 randomly generated numbers. Once they click the guess button the result is shown. To aid the user I am supposed to give them a hint when they hover the mouse over a label, the hint should be either 3 higher or 3 lower than the actual number. I cannot figure out how to get the random number generated when the user hits the guess button to equal the number as the hover event. Sorry for all the code, any help would be appreciated.

Here is how I am creating my random number:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    int[] rndArray = new int[100];

    public void getNumbers()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < rndArray.Length; x++)
        {
            rndArray[x] = random.Next(1, 100); 
        }
    }
```

Here is the guss button event:

```
 private void Guess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getNumbers();
        for (int x = 0; x < rndArray.Length; x++)
        {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) == rndArray[x])
                { 
                    result.Text = "You Win!";
                    correct.Text = "Correct: ";
                }
                else
                { 
                    result.Text = "Sorry - you loose; the number is: " + rndArray[x];
                    incorrect.Text = "Incorrect: ";
                }
        }
```

And the mouse hover event:

```
private void mouseHere_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getNumbers();
        for (int x = 0; x < rndArray.Length; x++)
            hint.Text = "It's not " + (rndArray[x] +- 3);
    }
```

Comment: "To aid the user I am supposed to give them a hint when they hover the mouse over a label, the hint should be either 3 higher or 3 lower than the actual number."  Which number?...you generated **100** of them (in the array)!  How does this game work?  Are they trying to guess every single number in the array separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three possible issues.

First, at the beginning of your mouse hover and guess click functions, you call GetNumbers, which generates 100 numbers and assigns them to the array. You should only generate them once per game. I would recommend calling it once at the beginning of each game (perhaps in the FormShown or FormLoad event handlers), and not calling it again until the next game begins. Otherwise, the numbers will keep changing.

Second, inside your mouse hover function, you have a for loop that assigns the text to "hint" 100 times. The first 99 hints will probably not be accurate, as the end of your mouse hover event will display the hint for the very last number. You will need to identify which array element to give a hint for, and assign it to the appropriate hint display.

Third, the `+-` operator is not an actual operator in C#. If this is actually compiling and running, it's probably interpreting it in a manner such as `hint.Text = "It's not " + (rndArray[x] + (-3);` I would recommend using a Random object to generate a number, then using whether it's odd or even to determine whether to add or subtract. Just make sure you don't reassign the array.

EDIT: With regards to figuring out whether to add or subtract from the hint, make sure you don't randomly generate a hint each time you hover; do it once for that number and store the hint. Otherwise, hovering over it a few times will show both possible hints.